# Mac OS Catalina - pecl install zip extension

Tags: php, zip, pear, pecl

I am trying to install **zip** extension by using **pecl** on Mac OS Catalina.

I am getting following error:

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [php73/php_zip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

**libzip** version - 1.6.1

**pcre** version - 8.44

I am trying to install zip extension to native apache developed by mac. As far I didn't find any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Homebrew

```
$(brew --prefix php@7.3)/bin/pecl install --force zip
```

Comment: Maybe it would be worth remarking that --force is only needed for unattended install? (I assume that is why you added that?) Since it's not super clear from the question whether unattended install is needed, and using it unnecessarily might be a bit unsafe.